Print values from json and html files stored in different folders with variable names
I'm automating some tests, every run generates a folder with a variable name. Inside every one of those folders there's a "statistics.json" and a "index.html".
For each folder I need to get some values from both files to populate a table: i used a foreach function but it only gets those values from one folder. I know this because the Start time is exactly the same for each row of the table.
So i have my main path
$path = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL";
$scan = scandir($path);

Then I'm creating an array with every folder in the path:
$folder = array();
    foreach($scan as $folders) {
    
    if($folders !== '.' && $folders !== '..'){ 
            $folder[] = $folders;

I do this because then I can create a path using the $folders variable in the middle, like so:
//json path
$path2 = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/".$folders."/statistics.json";  
    
//html path
$path4 = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/".$folders."/index.html";
    

I know this works because if I echo the values I get:

/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.10-12.03.11/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.10-12.08.06/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.23-15.30.53/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.23-15.48.04/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11_2024.06.30-22.14.24/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11_2024.07.09-12.08.05/statistics.json
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/miao/statistics.json

and

/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.10-12.03.11/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.10-12.08.06/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.23-15.30.53/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11-kibana_2024.07.23-15.48.04/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11_2024.06.30-22.14.24/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/FUC-UBIM11_2024.07.09-12.08.05/index.html
/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/miao/index.html

Since I am sitll in the foreach function, I now go with
$json = file_get_contents($path2);
$data = (array)json_decode($json);

And I know this works because if i echo $json I get:

{ "Kibana" : { "transaction" : "Kibana", "sampleCount" : 5,
"errorCount" : 5, "errorPct" : 100.0, "meanResTime" : 31505.8,
"medianResTime" : 31511.0, "minResTime" : 31495.0, "maxResTime" :
31514.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31514.0, "pct2ResTime" : 31514.0, "pct3ResTime" : 31514.0, "throughput" : 0.1586495748191395,
"receivedKBytesPerSec" : 0.6399589196757203, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0
}, "Total" : { "transaction" : "Total", "sampleCount" : 20,
"errorCount" : 5, "errorPct" : 25.0, "meanResTime" :
7944.549999999999, "medianResTime" : 135.0, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 31514.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31511.9, "pct2ResTime" :
31513.9, "pct3ResTime" : 31514.0, "throughput" : 0.610016470444702, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 1.2383215206185567, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
0.07163523493259318 }, "Kibana-0" : { "transaction" : "Kibana-0", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
12.6, "medianResTime" : 20.0, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 22.0, "pct1ResTime" : 22.0, "pct2ResTime" : 22.0, "pct3ResTime" : 22.0,
"throughput" : 227.27272727272725, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
276.0120738636364, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT-0" : { "transaction" : "MT-0", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0,
"errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 10.8, "medianResTime" : 9.0,
"minResTime" : 4.0, "maxResTime" : 25.0, "pct1ResTime" : 25.0,
"pct2ResTime" : 25.0, "pct3ResTime" : 25.0, "throughput" :
192.30769230769232, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 247.67127403846155, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT" : { "transaction" : "MT",
"sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
249.0, "medianResTime" : 246.0, "minResTime" : 245.0, "maxResTime" : 262.0, "pct1ResTime" : 262.0, "pct2ResTime" : 262.0, "pct3ResTime" : 262.0, "throughput" : 19.083969465648856, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 30.224982108778626, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 8.964247375954198 } } { "Kibana" : { "transaction" : "Kibana", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount"
: 5, "errorPct" : 100.0, "meanResTime" : 31543.0, "medianResTime" :
31541.0, "minResTime" : 31541.0, "maxResTime" : 31549.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31549.0, "pct2ResTime" : 31549.0, "pct3ResTime" : 31549.0,
"throughput" : 0.1584685598377282, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
0.6391049398611816, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "Total" : { "transaction" : "Total", "sampleCount" : 20, "errorCount" : 5,
"errorPct" : 25.0, "meanResTime" : 7946.349999999999, "medianResTime"
: 121.0, "minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 31549.0, "pct1ResTime" :
31542.8, "pct2ResTime" : 31548.7, "pct3ResTime" : 31549.0, "throughput" : 0.6097746882526907, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
1.237652062562883, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.07160684205311138 }, "Kibana-0" : { "transaction" : "Kibana-0", "sampleCount" : 5,
"errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 4.2,
"medianResTime" : 2.0, "minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 13.0,
"pct1ResTime" : 13.0, "pct2ResTime" : 13.0, "pct3ResTime" : 13.0,
"throughput" : 384.61538461538464, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
466.796875, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient-0" : { "transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient-0", "sampleCount" : 5,
"errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 9.2,
"medianResTime" : 8.0, "minResTime" : 3.0, "maxResTime" : 20.0,
"pct1ResTime" : 20.0, "pct2ResTime" : 20.0, "pct3ResTime" : 20.0,
"throughput" : 238.09523809523807, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
306.6871279761905, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient" : { "transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient", "sampleCount" : 5,
"errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 229.0,
"medianResTime" : 228.0, "minResTime" : 222.0, "maxResTime" : 238.0,
"pct1ResTime" : 238.0, "pct2ResTime" : 238.0, "pct3ResTime" : 238.0,
"throughput" : 20.920502092050206, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
33.13774843096235, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 9.826915533472803 } } { "Kibana" : { "transaction" : "Kibana", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount"
: 5, "errorPct" : 100.0, "meanResTime" : 31633.8, "medianResTime" :
31637.0, "minResTime" : 31628.0, "maxResTime" : 31637.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31637.0, "pct2ResTime" : 31637.0, "pct3ResTime" : 31637.0,
"throughput" : 0.15802281849499067, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
0.6374307168705161, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "Total" : { "transaction" : "Total", "sampleCount" : 20, "errorCount" : 5,
"errorPct" : 25.0, "meanResTime" : 7970.950000000001, "medianResTime"
: 115.5, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 31637.0, "pct1ResTime" :
31637.0, "pct2ResTime" : 31637.0, "pct3ResTime" : 31637.0, "throughput" : 0.607810363166692, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
1.233783809451451, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0713761681355417 }, "Kibana-0" : { "transaction" : "Kibana-0", "sampleCount" : 5,
"errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 3.6,
"medianResTime" : 2.0, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 12.0,
"pct1ResTime" : 12.0, "pct2ResTime" : 12.0, "pct3ResTime" : 12.0,
"throughput" : 416.6666666666667, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
506.02213541666663, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient-0" : { "transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient-0",
"sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
1.6, "medianResTime" : 1.0, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 4.0, "pct1ResTime" : 4.0, "pct2ResTime" : 4.0, "pct3ResTime" : 4.0,
"throughput" : 119.04761904761904, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
153.29706101190476, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient" : { "transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient", "sampleCount"
: 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 244.8,
"medianResTime" : 248.0, "minResTime" : 219.0, "maxResTime" : 257.0,
"pct1ResTime" : 257.0, "pct2ResTime" : 257.0, "pct3ResTime" : 257.0,
"throughput" : 19.45525291828794, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
30.80921692607004, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 9.138649075875486 } } { "Kibana" : { "transaction" : "Kibana", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount"
: 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 2470.0, "medianResTime" :
2423.0, "minResTime" : 2412.0, "maxResTime" : 2666.0, "pct1ResTime" : 2666.0, "pct2ResTime" : 2666.0, "pct3ResTime" : 2666.0, "throughput" : 1.8733608092918694, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 11.436648206257026, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.781176821843387 }, "Total" : { "transaction" :
"Total", "sampleCount" : 20, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0,
"meanResTime" : 690.9999999999999, "medianResTime" : 148.0,
"minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 2666.0, "pct1ResTime" : 2430.2,
"pct2ResTime" : 2654.25, "pct3ResTime" : 2666.0, "throughput" :
5.030181086519114, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 12.769979250503019, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 1.115088971327968 }, "MT" : { "transaction" :
"MT", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0,
"meanResTime" : 287.0, "medianResTime" : 288.0, "minResTime" : 284.0,
"maxResTime" : 290.0, "pct1ResTime" : 290.0, "pct2ResTime" : 290.0,
"pct3ResTime" : 290.0, "throughput" : 17.182130584192443,
"receivedKBytesPerSec" : 26.897417310996566, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
8.070903135738833 }, "Kibana-0" : { "transaction" : "Kibana-0", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
3.0, "medianResTime" : 1.0, "minResTime" : 0.0, "maxResTime" : 12.0, "pct1ResTime" : 12.0, "pct2ResTime" : 12.0, "pct3ResTime" : 12.0,
"throughput" : 19.841269841269842, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
24.104042658730158, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT-0" : { "transaction" : "MT-0", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0,
"errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" : 4.0, "medianResTime" : 2.0,
"minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 10.0, "pct1ResTime" : 10.0,
"pct2ResTime" : 10.0, "pct3ResTime" : 10.0, "throughput" :
416.6666666666667, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 528.9713541666666, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 } } { "Total" : { "transaction" : "Total",
"sampleCount" : 10, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime"
: 522.6999999999999, "medianResTime" : 511.5, "minResTime" : 488.0,
"maxResTime" : 581.0, "pct1ResTime" : 578.9, "pct2ResTime" : 581.0,
"pct3ResTime" : 581.0, "throughput" : 17.182130584192443,
"receivedKBytesPerSec" : 5.084165592783505, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
8.070903135738833 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient" : { "transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient", "sampleCount" : 10, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" :
0.0, "meanResTime" : 522.6999999999999, "medianResTime" : 511.5, "minResTime" : 488.0, "maxResTime" : 581.0, "pct1ResTime" : 578.9,
"pct2ResTime" : 581.0, "pct3ResTime" : 581.0, "throughput" :
17.182130584192443, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 5.084165592783505, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 8.070903135738833 } } { "Total" : { "transaction"
: "Total", "sampleCount" : 332003, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0,
"meanResTime" : 173.36791233813958, "medianResTime" : 148.0,
"minResTime" : 71.0, "maxResTime" : 42259.0, "pct1ResTime" : 252.0,
"pct2ResTime" : 291.0, "pct3ResTime" : 473.9800000000032, "throughput"
: 92.16552890459761, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 61.02366073956755,
"sentKBytesPerSec" : 44.552672663843566 }, "MT - OK - 1 recipient" : {
"transaction" : "MT - OK - 1 recipient", "sampleCount" : 332003,
"errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
173.36791233813958, "medianResTime" : 148.0, "minResTime" : 71.0, "maxResTime" : 42259.0, "pct1ResTime" : 252.0, "pct2ResTime" : 291.0,
"pct3ResTime" : 473.9800000000032, "throughput" : 92.16552890459761,
"receivedKBytesPerSec" : 61.02366073956755, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
44.552672663843566 } } { "Kibana" : { "transaction" : "Kibana", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 5, "errorPct" : 100.0, "meanResTime"
: 31631.2, "medianResTime" : 31632.0, "minResTime" : 31626.0,
"maxResTime" : 31635.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31635.0, "pct2ResTime" :
31635.0, "pct3ResTime" : 31635.0, "throughput" : 0.15803780264239206, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 0.6375528932770719, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0
}, "Total" : { "transaction" : "Total", "sampleCount" : 20,
"errorCount" : 5, "errorPct" : 25.0, "meanResTime" :
7963.650000000001, "medianResTime" : 113.5, "minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 31635.0, "pct1ResTime" : 31632.9, "pct2ResTime" :
31634.9, "pct3ResTime" : 31635.0, "throughput" : 0.6085686465433301, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 1.2355607579722494, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
0.071465214596519 }, "Kibana-0" : { "transaction" : "Kibana-0", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
1.0, "medianResTime" : 1.0, "minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 1.0, "pct1ResTime" : 1.0, "pct2ResTime" : 1.0, "pct3ResTime" : 1.0,
"throughput" : 500.0, "receivedKBytesPerSec" : 607.421875,
"sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT-0" : { "transaction" : "MT-0",
"sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0, "meanResTime" :
7.2, "medianResTime" : 7.0, "minResTime" : 1.0, "maxResTime" : 13.0, "pct1ResTime" : 13.0, "pct2ResTime" : 13.0, "pct3ResTime" : 13.0,
"throughput" : 384.61538461538464, "receivedKBytesPerSec" :
495.4176682692308, "sentKBytesPerSec" : 0.0 }, "MT" : { "transaction" : "MT", "sampleCount" : 5, "errorCount" : 0, "errorPct" : 0.0,
"meanResTime" : 215.2, "medianResTime" : 215.0, "minResTime" : 214.0,
"maxResTime" : 217.0, "pct1ResTime" : 217.0, "pct2ResTime" : 217.0,
"pct3ResTime" : 217.0, "throughput" : 23.041474654377883,
"receivedKBytesPerSec" : 36.49733582949309, "sentKBytesPerSec" :
10.823192684331797 } }

So it can read the whole content of every json file.
At this point I take the html file from every folder like so, and close the first <?php:
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($path4);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$trs = $dom->getElementById("generalInfos")->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach($trs as $key=>$tr){
    
        foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {           
}}}}

At this point I start my table and then open a new <?php again with:
$folder = array();
    foreach($scan as $folders) {
        if($folders !== '.' && $folders !== '..'){ 
            $folder[] = $folders;
        

Then I start getting the values I need from the two files:
from the json:
$name=($data["MT"]->transaction);
$req=($data["Total"]->sampleCount);   
$tp=($data["Total"]->throughput);
$roundNumber = round($tp, 3);
$err=($data["Total"]->errorCount);

and from the html:
$st = $xpath->query('//div/table/tr/td')->item(3);
$st1 = str_replace('"','',$st->textContent);                
$et = $xpath->query('//div/table/tr/td')->item(5);
$et1 = str_replace('"','',$et->textContent);

$st2 = strtotime($st1); 
$stD = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $st2);
$SThour=date_create('h:i:s',$st2);
    
$et2 = strtotime($et1); 
$etD = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $et2);
$EThour=date_create('h:i:s',$et2);
                
$diff = date('h:i:s', ($SThour -$EThour));
$diff1 = date('h:i:s', $diff)/ 30;
$diff2 = number_format((float)$diff1, 3, '.', '');

I close the second <?php and I go to populate the table:
<tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $folders;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $name;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $stD;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $diff2;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $req;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $roundNumber;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $err;?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $path3.$folders."/" ?>" target =’_blank’>LINK</a></h1></td>
            
            
</tr>

What I get is a table that actually shows as many rows as the folders in the path, but I think that's just because the first and the last  work just fine: every row starts with a list and ends with a link related to each different folder in the path.
As per the rest of the data, as you can see from this screenshot (sorry for the quality), it all comes from the same folder, clearly.

So please, how do i show the data in the table from the 2 files of each folder, instead of just from one?

I DID IT!
I merged the info that I placed before and after the table instructions:
This goes first
   <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
  <h1 align="center">Performance - Load Test</h1>
<table border="3" BORDERCOLOR=#F4982B align="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
    
        <th>Folder</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Requests</th>
        <th>Throughput</th>
        <th>Errors</th>
        <th>Report</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>

Then i go with all the data extractions under one single foreach function:
//mainPath 
$path = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL";
$scan = scandir($path);
$folder = array();
    foreach($scan as $folders) {
    
    if($folders !== '.' && $folders !== '..'){ 
            $folder[] = $folders;

            
//json path
$path2 = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/".$folders."/statistics.json";          
//echo $path2.'<br>';

//link path
$path3 = "/jmeter/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/";


//html path
$path4 = "/app/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/TestCri/Performance/fuc/FULL/".$folders."/index.html";
//echo $path4.'<br>';
    
    //il json

    $json = file_get_contents($path2);
    //echo $json.'<br>';
    $data = (array)json_decode($json);


    //l'html    

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($path4);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$trs = $dom->getElementById("generalInfos")->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach($trs as $key=>$tr){
    
        foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {           
}
}


        
                $name=($data["MT"]->transaction);
                $req=($data["Total"]->sampleCount);   
                $tp=($data["Total"]->throughput);
                $roundNumber = round($tp, 3);
                $err=($data["Total"]->errorCount);
                
                
                
                $st = $xpath->query('//div/table/tr/td')->item(3);
                $st1 = str_replace('"','',$st->textContent);                
                $et = $xpath->query('//div/table/tr/td')->item(5);
                $et1 = str_replace('"','',$et->textContent);

                $st2 = strtotime($st1); 
                $stD = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $st2);
                $SThour=date_create('h:i:s',$st2);
                //echo $SThour.'<br>';
                
                $et2 = strtotime($et1); 
                $etD = date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $et2);
                $EThour=date_create('h:i:s',$et2);
                //echo $EThour.'<br>';
                
                $diff = date('h:i:s', ($SThour -$EThour));
                $diff1 = date('h:i:s', $diff)/ 30;
                $diff2 = number_format((float)$diff1, 3, '.', '');

and then I close the table:
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $folders;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $name;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $stD;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $diff2;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $req;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $roundNumber;?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $err;?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $path3.$folders."/" ?>" target =’_blank’>LINK</a></h1></td>
            
            
</tr>


An effective way to merge data from two folders in the same database, I suggest using the mysql JOIN clause.  Example below:
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

